# Upload image and load in canvas, IE9, no FileApi support

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, file-upload

I have been creating an application which allows user to **upload images first and then load it in canvas**.

And I looked through various SO posts and online examples which allows the user to read the uploaded image and load it in canvas, and all the examples were using `HTML5 FileApi which IE9 doesn't support`.

Yes there are `Shims` available, which can replicate the FileApi functionality provided by the FileApi, but most of them depend upon `Flash` or `Silverlight`.

So, is there any **alternative** for the process, I **mean not only an alternative for FileApi, but can the whole process of uploading and loading images in canvas** can be done without using the FileAPI??

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to "upload the image first and then load it in the canvas", you do not need FileAPI, which is only useful for accessing the file data before upload.

Use a normal `<input type="file" />` for the upload, and have your server code output the file's path and name for the javascript to pick up and load the canvas.